# Android Accessibility support of multiple Text view

Tags: android, textview, accessibility, text-to-speech, multiple-views

I have a **parent view** consisting of **multiple TextViews** in it. For supporting accessibility I am facing a problem.

***Problem:*** When I touch the **parent view** all text views inside it reading out one after another. But I don't want that.

***What I want:*** when I will touch **specific textView** then the content of the text view will readout.
There is a **content description** in **ParentView**. I want just to read out the content description when touching the **ParentView**, not the text views.

tried with setting `setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);`
but not working like I expected.

How can I solve this problem?
Expectation in this picture.
[image: What I am expecting to show in this picture]